# Shellscript - Show error for specific argument when using mv

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I'm currently writing code for a script to move files to a "dustbin".
As it stands - the code works fine but I want it to produce a message when a file has been moved correctly and a message when a specific file has failed to move/doesn't exist.

My code will accept multiple filenames for input, e.g.

```
# del test1.txt *.html testing.doc
# Successfully moved to Dustbin
```

However if only one of these does not exist it still produces an error message.
How do I do this but still allow it to accept arguments as seen in the above example?

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv -u "$@" /root/Dustbin 2>/dev/null

# END OF SCRIPT
```

Sorry for what is probably an obvious question! I'm completely new to shellscript !

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to iterate over the arguments and try to move each one:

```
for path in "$@"; do
    if mv -u "$path" /root/Dustbin 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "Success"
    else
        printf 'Failed to move %s\n' "$path"
    fi
done
```

As a shorthand for iterating over the arguments you can omit `in "$@"` like

```
for path; do
    if mv -u "$path" /root/Dustbin 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "Success"
    else
        printf 'Failed to move %s\n' "$path"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you!
I knew I would have to go over each argument but didn't have a clue how to do it. I didn't even know we could use printf in bash - total newbie at this! :)